# Why is the corresponding prime ideal non zero if we have a non Archimedean value?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $|.|$ be the non Archimedean absolute value and
$O=\{x\in\ F| |x|\le1\}$ is the valuation ring,
$m=\{x\in\ F | |x|\lt1\}$ is a maximal ideal and $\text{Quot}(O)=F.$

Why is the corresponding prime ideal non zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You intend for (i) $F$ to be a number field and (ii) the absolute value to be nontrivial, but forgot to say that.

Show a nonarchmedean absolute value must be $\leq 1$ on $\mathcal O_F$.  If it were $1$ on all nonzero algebraic integers in $F$ then it would be $1$ on $F^\times$ (each element of $F^\times$ is a ratio of nonzero algebraic integers in $F$), so the absolute value would be trivial. Therefore when the absolute value is nontrivial we have a contradiction, which proves the absolute value is less than $1$ on some number in $\mathcal O_F$. So $m \cap \mathcal O_F \not= \{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much :)